# Spark Scala - reading Sequence files with multiple key types?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have sequence files that have keys of either `LongWritable` or `Text`.  The values are all the same format (json). I'd like to process them all at once in one spark job, but I can't figure out how to write the code so it works for both `Text` and `LongWritable` keys.  I actually don't even care about the sequence record keys in my job, I'm not using them.

Here's what I do for `LongWritable`.  How would I enhance it to work for both `LongWritable` and `Text` keys?  Is there someway to just load the sequence file record values and ignore the keys?

```
val rdd = sparkCtx.sequenceFile[Long, String](srcDir)

// put into Json records, don't care about seq key
val jsonRecs = rdd.map((record: (Long, String)) => new String(record._2))
```

Comment: Maybe you can read `Text` and `LongWritable` files separately and after discarding keys just `union` your rdds?

Comment: I don't really have an easy way to tell them apart.  However, I think I've found a way to do them both.  NullWritable seems to work for both as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution with NullWritable, works with both Text and LongWritable seq file keys.

I read from a local text file during local testing, and from HDFS when running on a cluster.

```
     var rdd = if (inputFileType.equalsIgnoreCase(InputFileType_Text)) {
        // Read local text file
        // Tried using a NullWritable here for local testing, but it throws
        // a 'Not Serializable' error.  Using null instead.
        sparkCtx.textFile(srcDir).map(line => {
           val tokens = line.split("\t")
           (null, tokens(1))
        })
     } else  {
        // Default to assuming sequence files are input
        // Read HDFS directory of seq files.
        log.debug("SEQUENCE files, srcDir={}", srcDir)
        sparkCtx.sequenceFile[NullWritable, String](srcDir)
     }
     log.debug("LOADED: rdd<NullWritable,String>")

     // Json records
     val jsonRecs = rdd.map((record: (NullWritable, String)) => new String(record._2))
```